# How to allow only the author of a post edit or delete it in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model and a question model.

In the user model:

```
has_many :questions
```

The question model:

```
belongs_to
```

in my questions/show.html.erb

```
<% if @question.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %> | <%= link_to 'Destroy', @question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this job?' } %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>
<% end %>
```

How can only the user that authored the question edit and delete it?

Comment: Your view part looks ok (for editing post). Are you asking how to implemented the controller part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), the authorization gem by Ryan Bates of [Railscasts](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). It's great for Rails authorization needs.

First, you'll create an `Ability` class that defines all of the abilities in the application.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, Question, user_id: user.id
  end
end
```

Then, you'll be able to easily integrate authorization into your controllers.

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    authorize! :manage, @question
    ...
  end
  def destroy
    authorize! :manage, @question
    ...
  end
end
```

And also customize your views.

```
<% if can? :manage, @question %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %> | <%= link_to 'Destroy', @question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this job?' } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you're using ActiveRecord, take a look at this gem I wrote : https://github.com/intrepidd/rails-canhaz I find it to be easier to use than cancan.

Answer (score 2):

All you need in your controller is:

```
def destroy
  @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
  @question.destroy

  render ... #anything you want to render
end
```

The previous code will ensure that an user can only delete his own questions. If the id of the question doesn't belongs to the user no question will be deleted and it would throw and `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Internal Server error`. You can add a `begin - rsecue block` to catch this exception an handle it as you want.

```
def destroy
  begin
   @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
   @question.destroy
   render or redirect_to ....
  rescue Exception ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
   flash[:notice] = 'not allow to delete this question'
   redirect_to ....
  end
end
```

Other simple way is to add a before filter in your controller

```
before_filter :require_authorization, only: [:delete]
...
def destroy
   @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
   @question.destroy
   render or redirect_to ....
   #With the before filter this code is only going to be executed if the question belongs to the user
end
...
private
def require_authorization
  redirect_to :root unless current_user.questions.find_by_question_id(params[:id])
  #Use the find_by to avoid the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound and get a nil instead in case the question id doesn't belong to a question of the user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing your `if` to the following:

```
<% if current_user.questions.include?(@question) %>
```

Also you can take a look at [:inverse_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#972-Undocumented-inverse-of-option)

Then in your Edit and Delete actions in the controller you can again check for the right user before showing the edit form or deleting the question.